# Button getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: button, ios5, exc-bad-access, ibaction, xcode4.2

im trying to create a simple app that allows you to switch views. I can go to the next view but when i click the back button i get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on this line in the main.m:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

This is the code im using to go back:

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender{
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

}

i cant figure out what the problem would be so any help is appreciated! thank you.

Comment: How are you getting to the second view?

Comment: Do you have the full callstack from the crash?  Theres probably more useful information in there

Comment: '-(IBAction)switchView:(id)sender {
    
    SecondView *MyViewController = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    
    [self.view addSubview:MyViewController.view];
    }'

Comment: thats how i get to the second page Dan F

Comment: when the program crashes it doesnt show anything in the debugging area  cwieland